# Generated table not showing up in correct location in paper

Tags: tables

So I'm using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ to generate a table for my overleaf LaTeX document. When pasting the code, the table is showing up in a different place in the paper than where I put the code would suggest. Does anyone know what the issue might be ??

Comment: Hi can you provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of your code so users can recreate your issue.

Comment: that is a feature: in latex tables can "float" to a place where they fit.

Comment: Is there a way to disable that?? I want the tables at the end of the paper, where there is plenty of room

Comment: See the `endfloat` package.

Comment: Man I added \usepackage[. . .]{endfloat}

to the beginning of my document, it added a whole new section called "list of tables" after like a page of blank space!! Can't it just let the table show up where it shows up in the code? seems like it shouldn't be this hard

Comment: You could add the `capt-of` package, remove the `table` environment and replace `\caption{...}` with `\captionof{table}{...}`.